# Can we use bot worms in an online game?

Tags: worms-revolution

Me and a friend got Worms Revolution and one of our favorite tings to do is play in a game with all non-player slots filled with CPU worms for more carnage. In local multiplayer this is still possible, but if you can do it in online multiplayer we haven't found out how.

Is there any way to create an online game with bots in Worms Revolution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment it is **not** possible to add CPU Teams into online multiplayer matches.

But it's [listed in the Team 17 Forum](http://forum.team17.com/showthread.php?t=56852) as a suggestion.